# caching CloudFront protected links with PHP AWS-SDK

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

we have a class for generating links to protected assets on S3 that we are also trying to link with cloudfront.

The AWS-SDK for php provides a caching mechanism for caching the generated links. This works fine for protected S3 links, but does not generate a cache for the CloudFront links.

Is this not supported?
or 
Is this a bug I should report to the maintainers?

```
//caching does not work here 
    function _generate_cf($bucket, $filename, $time){
        $this->_cf = new AmazonCloudFront();
        return $this->_cf->cache('1 hour')->get_private_object_url($bucket, $filename, $time);
    }

//caching does work here
    function _generate_s3($bucket, $filename, $time){
        $this->_s3 = new AmazonS3();
        return $this->_s3->cache('1 hour')->get_object_url($bucket, $filename, $time);
    }
```